# ionic2 - Photo Viewer not working

Tags: ionic2

**.html**

```
<img *ngIf=new.Preview_image1 src="{{new.Preview_image1}}" (click)="zoomImage(new)"/>
```

ionic document([ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-viewer/)) show me, `src="path"`, but I get the data form my service, but if I use `src="{{new.Preview_image1}}"` error showing.

**.ts**

```
  zoomImage(imageData) {
      this.photoViewer.show(imageData);
  }
```

I try use this, but when I build it in my ios device when I click the image, loading only no responing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `(click)="zoomImage(new)"` to `(click)="zoomImage(new.Preview_image1)"`.

```
<img *ngIf=new.Preview_image1 [src]="new.Preview_image1" (click)="zoomImage(new.Preview_image1)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. It is working now!! But why loading so slowly and have to press more than two times then showing